# Where can I get Lightroom Presets?

Tags: lightroom, presets, post-processing

Could you recommend a good source of presets for Lightroom?

Answer (score 5):

I really like [PresetsHeaven](http://www.presetsheaven.com/). It's the biggest collection of presets and examples I've found so far.

Answer (score 4):

One of the good resources is [LightroomKillerTip](http://lightroomkillertips.com)s blog by Matt Kloskowski.
Matt publishes new presets quite regularly and each post includes before/after example and the preset download.

- [Presets Section on LightroomKillerTips](http://lightroomkillertips.com/category/presets/)

Also

- [140 free Lightroom presets by Jack Davis](http://www.ononesoftware.com/detail.php?prodLine_id=33)
- [Lightroom Presets by Bryan Wheeler](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1651019)

Answer (score 1):

X Equals has lots of presets: [X-Equals](http://x-equals.com/blog/)

Also, if you go to the lightroom Plugin exchange, there are lots of presets as well as plugins

[Adobe Marketplace & Exchange](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/)